# Restassured returning bad request for x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, rest, api, rest-assured

String url = "url here";

```
    Response response = RestAssured
            .given()
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .header("authorization", "Basic bWFnZWxsYW5JRDo4dkVjQTc2dDhnOTgzQXEz")
            .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .header("postman-token", "18dd626d-a059-4fe4-c171-c5742d483c94")
            .formParam("grant_type", "password")
            .formParam("password", "Test123")
            .formParam("scope", "cn openid mail ")
            .formParam("username", "crew")
            .post(url);

    response.prettyPrint();
```

When working with Restassured on JAVA, and trying to generate a security token, it is returning bad request.

{
    "code": 400,
    "reason": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Bad Request"
}

Can someone please help in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the URL?

Comment: Which means your are not passing the required parameter to the url as expected. Try accessing the url with postman and see if you are getting proper response first. Then try to integrate with code.

Comment: @Minisha the url is correct and it is working fine on postman. but somehow it does not work with restassured. Is it bcoz restassured does not support x-www-form-urlencoded?